# Express $\lim_\limits{h\to 0} {f(x+2h) - f(x-h)\over h}$ in terms of $f’(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Given $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R$ and $f'$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$, use $f'(x)$ to express the following:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} {f(x+2h) - f(x-h)\over h}$$

Comment: kindly include your attempt.

Comment: Hint: $$f'(x):=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: It should be $3f'(x)$

Comment: $f(x+2h)-f(x)+f(x)-f(x-h)$

Comment: Thank you very much. ${ 3 f’(x)}$ is what I got too. There is just one middle step that needs to be proved.

Comment: Or that we use $\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+2h)-f(x-h)}{(x+2h)-(x-h)} = f'(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Why not to use Taylor expansion
$$f(x+k h)=f(x)+h k f'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 k^2 f''(x)+O\left(h^3\right)$$ which will show the limit and how it is approached.